how to find highest and lowest value of ttm squeeze range
Hello im trying to find the highest and lowest value of ttm squeeze range. i tried using ta.highiest but kept getting study error. i wanted to try save it in a list,  then use .sort to order it.
//@version=5
strategy(title="ttm Keltner Channels x Bollingerbands ", shorttitle="ttm", overlay=true)

//-----------------------------------//
//          kc settings              //
//----------------------------------//
import TradingView/ta/7
length = input.int(20, minval=1)
mult = input(2.0, "Multiplier")
src = input(close, title="Source")
exp = input(true, "Use Exponential MA", display = display.data_window)
BandsStyle = input.string("Average True Range", options = ["Average True Range", "True Range", "Range"], title="Bands Style", display = display.data_window)
atrlength = input(10, "ATR Length", display = display.data_window)
esma(source, length)=>
    s = ta.sma(source, length)
    e = ta.ema(source, length)
    exp ? e : s
ma = esma(src, length)
rangema = BandsStyle == "True Range" ? ta.tr(true) : BandsStyle == "Average True Range" ? ta.atr(atrlength) : ta.rma(high - low, length)
upper = ma + rangema * mult
lower = ma - rangema * mult
u = plot(upper, color=#2962FF, title="Upper")
plot(ma, color=#2962FF, title="Basis")
l = plot(lower, color=#2962FF, title="Lower")
fill(u, l, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 95), title="Background")
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//-----------------------------------//
//          bb settings             //
//----------------------------------//
lengthbb = input.int(20, minval=1)
maType = input.string("SMA", "Basis MA Type", options = ["SMA", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"])
srcbb = input(close, title="Source")
multbb = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="StdDev")

ma(sourcebb, lengthbb, _type) =>
    switch _type
        "SMA" => ta.sma(sourcebb, lengthbb)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(sourcebb, lengthbb)
        "SMMA (RMA)" => ta.rma(sourcebb, lengthbb)
        "WMA" => ta.wma(sourcebb, lengthbb)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(sourcebb, lengthbb)

basis = ma(src, lengthbb, maType)
dev = mult * ta.stdev(srcbb, lengthbb)
upperbb = basis + dev
lowerbb = basis - dev
offset = input.int(0, "Offset", minval = -500, maxval = 500, display = display.data_window)
plot(basis, "Basis", color=#2962FF, offset = offset)
p1 = plot(upperbb, "Upper", color=#F23645, offset = offset)
p2 = plot(lowerbb, "Lower", color=#089981, offset = offset)
fill(p1, p2, title = "Background", color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 95))
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//-----------------------------------//
//          ttm settings            //
//----------------------------------//
ttmsqueeze = upperbb < upper and lowerbb >  lower // ttm squeeze range
notttmsqueeze =  not ttmsqueeze //  no squeeze happening
ttmopen = (ttmsqueeze and not ttmsqueeze[1] )// open of ttm
ttmclose = (notttmsqueeze and not notttmsqueeze[1]) // close of ttm
plotshape(ttmsqueeze, color = color.blue) 
plotshape(ttmopen , color= color.green)
plotshape(ttmclose , color= color.red)
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Find the hightest & lowest price of range 

var float ttmopen_price = na // set to 0 to be updated
if (ttmopen) // when ttm first appears
    ttmopen_price := open // holds the price of ttmopen

var float ttmclose_price = na // set to 0 to be updated
if (ttmclose) // when ttm  appears last 
    ttmclose_price := close // holds the price of ttclose

var float currentsqueeze =na  // loop that thorugh ttmsqueeze
if (notttmsqueeze == not true) //when notttmsqueeze isnt equal to not true  
    currentsqueeze := close // update currentsqueeze to current close 

// find highest number in the range in of ttmopen_price and ttmclose_price
 // get each vaule in ttmsqueeze range
 // put in range 
 //sort each vaule high to low 

//ideas
// for loops // loop through save list and use sort to order high to low 
//araay.size // get elements
//array.sort // set ascending order 
//array,range // get range
//ta.barsince // use to get length of bars

idea to use for loops to loop through currentsqueeze and save list and use sort to order high to low. I also trying to use ta.barsince to get use as the length for ta.highiest

var ttm squeeze is bool. higher or  lower cannot be calculated.

so absolutely no work around ?
